# conditional formatting SEARCH and LEN

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I just want to ask a help for my excel formula.
I was having a hard time by trying a conditional formatting and formula these scenario:

1. To Search and highlight a cell that doesn't start with "S" Prefixes and 11 Characters.

Hope to help me with this and I will thank you forever if we came up a solution to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain more about "a cell that doesn't start with "S" Prefixes and 11 Characters"?

Do you mean this cell need to meet 2 conditon at the same time, one is starting with characters excludes "S", another one is its character length is 11?

[image]

On the image, I use the formula `=AND(LEFT(A1,1)<>"S",LEN(A1)=11)` to hihglight the cell.

Any misunderstanding, please let me know.